# Adding Metadata to Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to create a system that will, on every RMI call,

1) gather some data about the current local system state  (let's say the system time)

2) serialize it and transparently add it to the data sent over the wire with the call (ie, without changing the signature of the stub method being called)

3) deserialize it on the other side and take some action (let's say logging it to a file)

4) do the same thing in reverse when the method returns

I've was trying at first to do this with AspectJ, adding a pointcut at java.rmi.server.RemoteRef's invoke method that would allow me to add the metadata to the params Object array, but I've now discovered that AspectJ can't advise already-compiled code, which makes a lot of sense.

So, what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you using RMI-IIOP?  If so, you want to use an ORB interceptor with ServiceContext.  Otherwise, I don't think there's a convenient way to do it.

Comment: The system as it currently exists uses normal RMI, but I could potentially modify it. I don't know much of anything about RMI-IIOP; is it easy/possible to convert? Can you point me towards some resources on how to do it?

Comment: Start at the RMI/IIOP technotes: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi-iiop/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if I am getting enough context from what you are saying, but I think you could write the metadata upon serialization/deserialization of objects passed to and received from the server.

For instance, let's say you server is returning Jedi instances. And Jedi is a Serializable class. Then you could use the writeObject() and readObject() methods (as explained in the Java Serialization Specification) to write whatever special additional information that you may need at the client/server side.

For instance:

```
public class Jedi {
  ....
        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        stream.writeObject(new Date());
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Date sysDate = (Date) stream.readObject();
        System.out.println(sysDate);
        stream.defaultReadObject();
    }
}
```

The only problem as that you would be forced to do this for every serializable object you interchange with your server.

Comment: oooo! I think I like this idea. It sounds like it could be something I can do with AspectJ to save having to modify every class. Thanks! (Will accept if works how it sounds like it will :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also investigate RMI/JERI in the Jini 2 project. JERI stands for Java Extensible Remote Invocation protocol, i.e. you can customize it in numerous ways.

Comment: Given that I have a fairly large existing codebase to convert, do you think JERI or IIOP would be an easier transition? It would be nice to know before I dive into one or the other :)

Comment: @PersonMan RMI/IIOP would probably be a lot easier, but you need to do a dry-run with just one remote object to see whether you can do it at all. It might be simpler to add the required parameters to all the remote methods.